# Invariant subspaces of tensor product of irreducible and trivial representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $$S:X\to L(U)$$ be linear irreducible representation of some set $X$. Let $Z$ be some vector space. Now let's define $$R=S\otimes Id: X\to L(U\otimes Z),\ R(x) (u\otimes z) =(S(x)u)\otimes z.$$

Now if $Z$ has a basis $\{z_1,...,z_m\}$, then there is a decomposition $$U\otimes Z=(U\otimes z_1)\oplus ... \oplus (U\otimes z_m), $$ every summand is invariant and restriction of $R$ on it is isomorphic to $S$.

Now there is a statement that every invariant subspace of $U\otimes Z$ looks like $U\otimes Z_0$, where $Z_0$ is a subspace of $Z$. It's said that as sum of such tensor products is tensor product of the same form we need to study only minimal invariant subspaces.

Now let $W\subset U\times Z$ be a minimal invariant subspace. According to our decomposition every element $w\in W$ can be written as $$w=u_1\otimes z_1+...+u_m\otimes z_m.$$

And now there is a statement that bothers me. It's said that $w$ can be written as
$$w=\varphi_1(w)\otimes z_1+...+\varphi_m(w)\otimes z_m$$
where $\varphi_i$ is some morphism between $R_W$ and $S$.

I think I can see that these are isomorphisms between isomorphic representations $R_W$ and $S$. But I can't see why every $u_i$ appears from the same $w$ and not from different $w_i$.

**Upd**: Now I have an idea that it's how we define these $\varphi_i$ on every $w\in W$. Does it make sense?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez A course in algebra by Vinberg, chapter 11 §1.